# Disable moving around in mapview

Tags: android, android-mapview

Is it possible to disable moving inside the google map?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Even though there is an accepted answer, just providing my answer as it didnt help me. 
mapView.setClickable(false) does not work all the time, like cases where you have a mapView inside a scrollView. So I created a view object right above the mapView of the same size.

Handled the onTouchListener for my overlay view and passed all the touch events to the parent of mapView (ScrollView in my case), hence by-passing all the touch events from mapView to scrollview.

One more way to achieve is by doing

```
mMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Works for v2 map fragments too!

Answer (score 13):

```
mMap.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(false);
```

this can disable moving in map

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to setClickable(false), but you'll also probably want to setFocusable(false) in order to prevent the MapView from getting focus.

That can be a problem when the user uses the hardware navigation buttons, because if the MapView has focus then the up-down-left-right buttons will scroll the map.

Answer (score 1):

Simply do `scrollGesturesEnabled: false,`

Answer (score 0):

I created customMapView that extends MapView 
and override the onInterceptTouchEvent method.

```
public class customMapView extends MapView {
    public customMapView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public customMapView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
        super(context, attributeSet);
    }

    public customMapView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet, int i) {
        super(context, attributeSet, i);
    }

    public customMapView(Context context, GoogleMapOptions googleMapOptions) {
        super(context, googleMapOptions);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

//      return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can stop user interactions with **MapView** or **SupportMapFragment** using **GoogleMapOptions**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val mapOptions = GoogleMapOptions()
        mapOptions.rotateGesturesEnabled(false)
        mapOptions.zoomGesturesEnabled(false)
        mapOptions.tiltGesturesEnabled(false)
        mapOptions.scrollGesturesEnabled(false)

        // Map View
        val mapView = MapView(context, mapOptions)
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        // Or
        val mapView = MapView(context
        mapView.getMapAsync { googleMap ->
           googleMap.uiSettings.setAllGesturesEnabled(false) 
        }

       // Or Map Fragment
       val mapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance(mapOptions)
}
```

Comment: Could you please put a comment while down voting ? Otherwise no one (especially me) will know whats wrong with this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i have miss understood but what solved this issue for me was as follows :)

map.HasZoomEnabled = false;
map.HasScrollEnabled = false;

Answer (score -1):

If you embed the map view in your app, I think you can use static maps to view the same.

Comment: what do you mean by static maps?

Comment: static maps are a kind of snap shot of the map for a specific location. You can zoom in and zoom out but not much can be done.

Comment: I added an overlay to the map and I want to drag it around but I don't want the map to move too

Answer (score -4):

Perhaps this could be a solution:

mapView.setEnabled(false)