# mapview inside scrollivew flickers

Tags: android, android-layout, android-mapview, android-scrollview

In a layout I need to present a map inside a `scrollview`. Everything seems right at first, but there is issue with the map when I start scrolling inside `scrollview`, `mapview` flickers on top and bottom of the mapview a black flickering appears.

```
            <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
                android:id="@+id/mapview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

it's the code of map I am using it's inside a relative layout which in turn is inside a linear layout, which is actually inside a `scrollview`.

you can checkout how layout looks by using below url. Sorry guys I don't have enough reputation for posting images on stack over flow.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/xdf4tukvtnx5bq0/stack%20over%20flow%20map.png?dl=0

here above as you can see is map showing inside a scrollview. When I scroll it flickers and black appear on top and bottom of it.
I try to figure out possible reasons of it. My guess is it is something related to touch events of scrollview being passed to mapview, that's why this is happening. But I don't know how to remove those views. I am good if is there any way which makes map static and when on click it's becomes dynamic.

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28452115/295004 and/or consider Lite Mode: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/lite

Comment: @MorrisonChang I tried it. it just disable all gestures but the problem still remains.

Comment: As suggested in the link - did you try the view object over the map to capture the touch events?

Comment: @MorrisonChang I appreciate your effort, but all those things pointed out on that page isn't helping.