# Is there a way to change camera move gestures in Android GoogleMaps?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I new in Android. I try to find info about how to disable to move camera on Google Maps and change it destiny. For example when the marker will be displayed I couldn't move camera, and my move gestures will for example change to other options. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can:

1) disable all gestures like in answers for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5514187/6950238) question of [Vincent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/489856/vincent):

> `mMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(false);`

2) create touchable wrapper for `MapFragment` like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14538765/6950238) community wiki answer:

> ```
> public class TouchableWrapper extends FrameLayout {
>
>     public TouchableWrapper(Context context) {
>         super(context);
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
>
>         switch (event.getAction()) {
>
>             case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
>                   MainActivity.mMapIsTouched = true;
>                   break;
>
>             case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
>                   MainActivity.mMapIsTouched = false;
>                   break;
>
>             // ... and so on for all of the gestures your need 
>         }
>         return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
>     }
> }
> ```

For example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46372495/6950238) you can find example for "two finger scrolling gesture" touchable wrapper:

> ```
> public class TouchableWrapper extends FrameLayout {
>
>     private LockableScrollView mLockableScroll;
>     private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
>
>     public TouchableWrapper(Context context) {
>         super(context);
>     }
>
>     public void setGoogleMapAndScroll(GoogleMap googleMap, LockableScrollView lockableScroll) {
>         mGoogleMap = googleMap;
>         mLockableScroll = lockableScroll;
>     }
>
>
>     @Override
>     public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
>
>         switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
>
>             case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
>                 mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(false);
>                 // UPDATE: add below line to disable zoom gesture
>                 mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(false);
>                 mLockableScroll.setScrollingEnabled(true);
>             break;
>
>             case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
>                 mLockableScroll.setScrollingEnabled(false);
>                 mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(true);
>                 // UPDATE: add below line to enable zoom gesture
>                 mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);
>
>             break;
>
>             case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
>                 // UPDATE: add below line to disable zoom gesture
>                 mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(false);
>                 mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(false);
>                 mLockableScroll.setScrollingEnabled(true);
>             break;
>
>             case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
>                 // UPDATE: add below line to disable zoom gesture
>                 mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(false);
>                 mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(false);
>                 mLockableScroll.setScrollingEnabled(true);
>             break;
>         }
>         return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
>     }
> }
> ```